# Adding grids in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am designing a graphical application in WPF and net 4.5. I want to use the MVVM pattern and to not break it I would like to use as less code behind as possible.

The application should start with a window that contains a line graph, that is easy enough :)
When the user chooses so he can add another line graph, or a data pane. And that indefinitely, as shown in the picture below.

[image: Window layout]

The user should be able to resize these windows. There will also be some sort of scrolling in the graph panes and all the line graphs there should scroll together.

I was thinking to use a grid for this. I would be able to accomplish this hard coded, but I am wondering if it is possible to do this solely relying on XAML.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible to do in XAML. Use [@Rachel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel)'s [Grid Helper](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) and an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/).

Comment: Looks promising. Will run some tests with it.

Comment: This is all UI, and has nothing to do with MVVM.  Or at least shouldn't, as the VM should not be participating in UI layout.

Comment: @Will unless the UI layout is part of the application's Data set, and the OP wishes to "store" the layout or otherwise perform data-related operations based on it.

Comment: @HighCore: Wow, you split that hair right in half!

Comment: A `Grid` probably wouldn't be easy if you're looking for something like your last image. You'll probably want an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `Canvas`, and bind/store `Top`, `Left`, `Height`, and `Width` of each panel. Depending on if you allow your panels to be nested, you could possibly use a `DockPanel` or `Grid` instead, but a `Canvas` would probably be easiest

Comment: @Rachel the reason I wanted to use a grid is that by using a GridSplitter I get resizing for "free"

Comment: @MPL Hrrmm your best bet would probably be to google around for an existing custom panel with this functionality, or build your own then. An `ItemsControl` won't work with `GridSplitters` because it wraps each item in a `ContentPresenter`, and you'd need some way to insert the `GridSplitter` between the `ContentPresenters`, which means a custom panel